# How to create an array of substrings

Tags: bioinformatics

Say I have a variable, sequence, which is a string.

```
> sequence="AAAGCATATGCTAGCCCGTATAGCGATACTAGCTATACGATATATATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG"
```

I want to create an array, say seq, in which each element is a 3 character substring of the intial sequence, so something like

```
echo $seq[1]
echo $seq[2]
echo $seq[n]
```

gives:

```
AAA  
GCA
TAG
```

Where n is the last element of the array. 
Can someone please write the script to do this?
This is a weird combo of unix and C++ code of what I am trying to do, but I need it to be all unix

```
sequence="AAAGCATATGCTAGCCCGTATAGCGATACTAGCTATACGATATATATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG"
array_name=(seq) while($i+2<length(sequence)) {
seq[i]=substring(sequence,i,3)  i=i+3 }
```

Comment: No, sorry, we won't just write the script for you. Please try _something_ and then you can ask for help with the specific thing you are trying. We don't even know what language you need to use. Is that supposed to be PHP? Perl? Shell? Python? Something else?

Comment: Okay give me a minute

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a C++ question

Comment: No please don't, I know how to do this in C++ but I need to do this in terminal using bash

Comment: then explain: "but I need it to be all C++"

Comment: @pLumo it looks like it only did got seq = AAA? I typed in

Comment: >echo $seq
AAA
>echo $seq[2]
AAA[2]

Comment: @MridulaMMenon the array elements in bash need the braces, try with `echo ${seq[0]}`, `echo ${seq[1]}`, etc. Also notice that the subscripts start from `0` not from `1` as in `awk`, `zsh`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are doing this in `bash`:

```bash
sequence="AAAGCATATGCTAGCCCGTATAGCGATACTAGCTATACGATATATATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG"

for (( i = 0; i < ${#sequence}; i += 3 )); do
    printf '%s\n' "${sequence:i:3}"
done
```

This iterates over the length of the sequence, three base-pairs at a time.  In each iteration, the next group of three bases is printed.

To put these in an array, `seq`, instead of printing them out:

```bash
sequence="AAAGCATATGCTAGCCCGTATAGCGATACTAGCTATACGATATATATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG"

for (( i = 0; i < ${#sequence}; i += 3 )); do
    seq+=( "${sequence:i:3}" )
done
```

This gives you the array `seq`.  The individual array elements are available as `"${seq[0]}"`, `"${seq[1]}"`, etc.

To get the other two [reading frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reading_frame), change the loop so that it starts at 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

If your string does not contain spaces or newlines, you can use `grep` to separate your string and create an array:

```bsh
sequence="AAAGCATATGCTAGCCCGTATAGCGATACTAGCTATACGATATATATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG"
seq=( $(printf '%s' "$sequence" | grep -o ... ) )
```

or use `fold` instead of `grep`:

```bsh
seq=( $(printf '%s' "$sequence" | fold -b3 ) )
```

Compared to `grep`, this will let the last single character (`G`) be an array element too.

---

**Note**: If your string contains `*`, this might lead to problems in some circumstances. E.g. if you get `seq=( AT* ATA ATG )` and you have file names starting with `AT` in the current working directory, it will expand to the filenames instead. You could use `set -o noglob` to prevent globbing.

**Better alternative**: use  `readarray` instead of `seq=(...)` :

```
readarray seq < <(printf '%s' "$sequence" | fold -b3 )
```

*(credits for this @Kusalananda)*

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, processing long strings with loops and indexes can be *very* slow, as an alternative you can `read` the string and build an array:

```
sequence="AAAGCATATGCTAGCCCGTATAGCGATACTAGCTATACGATATATATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG"

declare -a seq=( "" )
while read -n 3 -r triple ; do seq+=( "$triple" ); done <<< "$sequence"
declare -p seq
```

The array is created with index 0 of an empty string so your indexes are from 1 as requested.

The way this works is to use "`read -n 3`" to read three characters at a time into variable `triple`, add it to the array (`+=`), using the `<<<` redirection to present the sequence on `stdin`. `read` handles cases where the input is not a multiple of 3.

(As coded above, this is good at reading unbroken sequences of letters — this is not a general purpose "split" routine as it has no special handling of whitespace, escape characters, nul bytes etc. If you set `IFS=""` then `read` will preserve whitespace in the input. If you need to remove spaces from the input you can use `... <<< ${sequence// /}`.

This is a special case of the more general problem  [Split string into an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/split-string-into-an-array-in-bash/30744597), wherein you can also read about all the exciting pitfalls for the unwary programmer. )